# imakeidx: How to enter a mathematical symbol?

Tags: unicode, imakeidx

I have a file with a math-symbol in the Index, that works fine with the combination of `imakeidx/makeindex` but reverting it to `imakeidx/xindy` it just won't work:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}
%\makeindex

\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

angle\index{angle}
$\alpha$\index{$\alpha$}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

When processed with `xelatex -shell-escape file.tex` we get:

```
Processing index...
ERROR: CHAR: index 0 should be less than the length of the string
system returned with code 256
```

I need to keep on using `texindy` because of the UTF-8 sorting of index entries with accented characters. The manual seems to indicate that `makeindex` and `xindy` are sort of interchangeable, and does not mention anything for entering math notation in the index entries, so this difference in the input notation surprises a bit. So what is the correct way to enter math symbols in an index entry of `imakeidx` with `texindy`?

Answer (score 2):

`texindy` does not accept a non-alphabetical character as a sorting key -- which in itself is a travesty because texindy takes Language and Codepage as arguments ... so you have to provide the sorting key as in:

```
 \index{alpha@$\alpha$}
```

if you are writing in English and

```
 \index{alfa@$\alpha$}
```

if you are writing in Portuguese. If the non-alphabetical part is located in a sub-index that needs to be sorted, there too you need to place a sorting key, as in:

```
  \index{function!psi@$\psi$}
```